# Android fragments overlaps each other don't want to set back ground color

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know this question has been asked nubmer of times but I haven't got valid solution yet

Following is my Fragment container in MainActivity

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="40dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Now as you can see app:behavior_overlapTop due to this I don't want to set background color to my fragment

I have added  `android:clickable="true"` to **root layout** in fragment.

Following is my code to add a fragment :-

```
  FacilityCategoriesGridFragment facilityCategoriesGridFragment = FacilityCategoriesGridFragment.newInstance();
                            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                                            android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                                    .add(R.id.main_content, facilityCategoriesGridFragment, "test")
                                    .addToBackStack(null)
                                    .commit();
                            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Now sometimes fragments are overlapping I don't want to use replace how I can I fix this?

Comment: you dont wanna `replace` but you dont wanna `add color` what do you exactly want ? **replace without replacing** ,how is that even possible ? would white color work then you can set white background ??

Comment: the solution of the question is within the question itself , **Add** means **adding one above another** https://www.google.co.in/search?q=add+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN774IN774&oq=add+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1823j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 and **Replace** means https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN774IN774&ei=HL2jWuXkBJXGvwSyoZOQBw&q=replace+meaning&oq=replace+meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i67k1j0i7i30k1l7.39637.40550.0.41236.7.7.0.0.0.0.307.936.0j1j2j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..5.2.551....0.Fd8DTnMT1KM

Comment: yeah but I don't want to replace fragment since it recreates previous fragment on backpress

Comment: `FragmentTransaction` has the [`hide()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) and [`show()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) methods.

Comment: This should be the same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633598/android-fragments-overlap-eachother/55649322#55649322

Comment: guess same reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633598/android-fragments-overlap-eachother/55649322#55649322

Answer (score 0):

Do `FacilityCategoriesGridFragment` `root` layout, `RecyclerView` and `GridView` has **android:layout_width="match_parent"** and
    **android:layout_height="match_parent"** ?

Comment: If you don't want to set background to fragment, set background to **windowBackground** in your **AppTheme**